# Can we add default values in Azure API Management while importing API Azure functions

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-functions, openapi, azure-api-management

There is option to add default values for the API through Azure Portal. Can we add some comments/attribute with the azure functions so that while importing them in APIM the default values comes automatically, if not what can be the best method to do so.

Answer (score 0):

After Azure Function is imported into APIM you can go and modify any aspect of imported API, i.e. add/remove parameters, provide descriptions, request/response samples, default values for parameters e.t.c.

Comment: yes that we can do from the portal, but I wanted to know if I can do that via code, like to create swagger UI we can just add attributes and comments on top of functions.

Comment: During import APIM only reads very specific subset of information about your function. There is no way to augment that. After function is imported you can use any of the tools APIM provides to do modifications: portal UI, swagger editor like UI we have in portal, form editors, API calls, powershell e.t.c.

Comment: ok but I was thinking like function.json is created automatically so there can be some way to add other attributes like [functionName] to add other info. Are you sure about it or should I post on github related to this.

Comment: Currently import ronly: reads list of functions, if necessary creates function key to authenticate APIM, reads hosting config to check if function app has URL prefix. For sure, you could create item on Github and describe in more detail how would you like to augment import.